# How to call a 'view' using callablestatement

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, callable-statement

I thought it would be a simple google search, but I can't find an answer to this:

I'm moving Access db to SQL Server, I have turned some of the queries into views. My Java application used to call every query using simple:

```
{ call dbo.GetOtherRanges() } //Well, not entirely true - Access did not use 'dbo' schema in front of the name
```

This works for stored procedures. But when I do that on views I receive the following:

```
[SQL Server]The request for procedure 'GetOtherRanges' failed because 'GetOtherRanges' is a view object.
```

I thought it would be as simple as removing the `()` brackets after the name of the view, but that didn't do the trick.

- How do I 'call' the views using JDBC CallableStatment?
- Is there a different way of calling table-valued functions as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Views` can be accessed just like `Tables` in JDBC.

You dont need a `CallableStatement` for this.

Just using `Statement` or `PreparedStatement` should be enough.

In case you need help how-to, following is a sample code found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/overview/)
Use view name instead of Table1

```
public void connectToAndQueryDatabase(String username, String password) {

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                         "jdbc:myDriver:myDatabase",
                         username,
                         password);

    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT a, b, c FROM Table1");

    while (rs.next()) {
        int x = rs.getInt("a");
        String s = rs.getString("b");
        float f = rs.getFloat("c");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ohh... that's disappointing. Now I either have to create a new class that deals with this or re-write all the affected views into sprocs.
Neither is ideal, but I'm leaning towards the second solution.
Cheers.